# Using and HTMLHelper to display an image in .backstretch

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I am using backstretch to provide a full height/width image background.  I am doing a little themeing and need to be able to call an image from the HTML Helper into the backstretch javascript.  It won't pull the image in for some reason.  It seems to be adding my MVC View root, which is Account onto it.  Here is my code:

```
$.backstretch('@Html.ThemeImage("login-background.jpg")');
```

The backstretch javascript is here:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/srobbin/jquery-backstretch/master/jquery.backstretch.min.js

the link its producing is this

```
http://localhost/xxx.xxx.xxx/Account/%3Cimg%20src=%22/xxx.xxx.xxxx
/Content/Client/Images/login-background.jpg%22%20/%3E
```

The actual url should be

```
http://localhost/xxx.xxxxxxx.xxx/Content/Client/Images/login-background.jpg
```

This is the extension control

```
ublic static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString ThemeImage(this HtmlHelper helper, string fileName, string alt = "", int width = 0, int height = 0, string cssClass = "", string id = "")
    {
        var clientFolder = string.Format("{0}/Content/{1}/Images", HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath, AppSettings.ClientName);
        var fullFileName = string.Format("{0}/{1}", clientFolder, fileName);

        var builder = new TagBuilder("img");
        builder.MergeAttribute("src", fullFileName);
        if (alt != "")
        {
            builder.MergeAttribute("alt", alt);
        }
        if (width != 0)
        {
            builder.MergeAttribute("width", width.ToString());
        }
        if (height != 0)
        {
            builder.MergeAttribute("height", height.ToString());
        }
        if (cssClass != "")
        {
            builder.MergeAttribute("class", cssClass);
        }
        if (id != "")
        {
            builder.MergeAttribute("id", id);
        }
        //var imgString = String.Format("<img src='{0}' alt='{1}' width='{2}' height='{3}' class='{4}' id='{5}'/>", fullFileName, alt, width, height, cssClass, id);

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
    }
}
```

I believe my extension control needs to be changed, but I can't figure out where.

Comment: Check the value of `AppDomainAppVirtualPath`. You may need to do something like `string root = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath; if (root == "/") {root = string.Empty;}`

Comment: Thank you Stephen.  I think I've narrowed it down to the controller wanting to inser <img src= into the code when i just need the image path.

Comment: Its stating Request and Content don't resolve

Comment: @TheDizzle, the link you are creating suggests its relative to the page you are on (i.e. `/Account..`), not relative to the application (which means `AppDomainAppVirtualPath` is `"/"`)

Comment: I got it pulling from the right path but with this code its adding <img src= onto the path. I dont need that I just need the relative path.  How can I get rid of the img src and still use this file to pull the image?

Comment: I cant tell from the min.js file what `$.backstretch` does and what parameter it accepts, but your passing it an image tag by using the `ThemeImage` extension method so of course it will add `<img scr ..`. If you are wanting to pass a path to the function, you can just use `$.backstretch('@Url.Content("~/Images/YourImage.jpg")');`